# What is the difference between numeric(19,0) and bigint in POSTGRES?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to map the java type to the SQL type and I encountered such a scenario.

If I elaborate, I was using the `auto-ddl` api to apply scripts to my database while starting my `spring` container. Now I am trying to generate the scripts using `liquibase` by generating the `db-changelog` for `POSTGRE` server.

Are `numeric(19,0)` and `BIGINT` same in Postgres server? Please put some light on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110880/numeric-vs-integer-for-a-column-size-and-performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`BIGINT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) range is `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`, so you can't store a number greater than `9223372036854775807`, but `NUMERIC (19, 0)` can do.

Please find the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (NumVal NUMERIC (19,0), IntVal BIGINT);

INSERT INTO TestTable (NumVal, IntVal) VALUES
('9223372036854775808', 9223372036854775807);

SELECT * FROM TestTable;
```

Here you can't store `9223372036854775808` in to `BIGINT`, but you can store the same value or greater than the value to `NUMERIC (19, 0)`

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=78a317f11d5acca24cbb0960f399355a) for the same.

Answer (score 9):

The main difference is the storage:

- `bigint` (and `smallint` and `integer`) are stored as integer values in the processor's native format (usually [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary numbers).

  The range is limited (but high), the storage space occupied is 8 bytes, and arithmetic is blazingly fast.
- `numeric` is stored as [binary coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) of variable length.

  The range and the precision is almost unlimited (up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point), but arithmetic operations are comparatively slow.

Answer (score 3):

`Numeric` has variable storage size, while `bigint` is always 8 bytes.

```
SELECT pg_column_size(123456789112345678911111555678::numeric(30,0)) AS numeric30,
       pg_column_size(1234567891123456789::numeric(19,0)) AS numeric19,
       pg_column_size(123::numeric(19,0)) AS numeric3,
       pg_column_size(1234567891123456789::bigint) AS bigint;

numeric30|numeric19|numeric3|bigint
---------|---------|--------|------
       22|       16|       8|     8
```

Additionaly, from [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) (emphasis mine):

> Calculations with numeric values yield exact results where possible,
>   e.g. addition, subtraction, multiplication. However, calculations on
>   numeric values are **very slow** compared to the integer types, or to the
>   floating-point types described in the next section.